# How to calculate pulling Object?

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, calculation

I would like to generate a kind of moving object that "follows" another object. You can imagine it like a car with 2 ropes (back left and back right) pulling a small sled after it.

I don't know for sure how I can calculate the position of this sled if I have both the direction (x, y) and the rotation of the car.

I have illustrated the car in the canvas here - How can I draw two ropes from the end of the car to the beginning of the sled and always pull it (physically correct) behind my car?

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let pos = {},
  size = {},
  velocity = {};

let init = function() {
  pos = {
    x: 140,
    y: 40,
    r: 0
  }
  size = {
    w: 20,
    h: 10
  }
  velocity = {
    x: 2,
    y: 3
  }
}
init()


let draw = function() {
  velocity.x += Math.random() * (0.1) - 0.1;
  velocity.y += Math.random() * (0.1) - 0.1;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  pos.x += velocity.x
  pos.y += velocity.y
  pos.r = ((180 / Math.PI) * Math.atan2(velocity.y, velocity.x) + 360) % 360;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(pos.x - size.w / 2, pos.y - size.h / 2)
  ctx.rotate(pos.r * (Math.PI / 180))
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size.w, size.h)
  ctx.restore()
  
  drawPulledObject()
}

let drawPulledObject = function() {
  // ?
}

setInterval(() => draw(), 100)
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input onclick="init()" type="button" value="rerun">
```

[image: im]

I'd appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you may need something like this: [Dragging Two Segments](http://users.polytech.unice.fr/~strombon/camash/Foundation%20HTML5%20Animation%20with%20JavaScript/html5-animation-source-code/examples/ch14/03-two-segment-drag.html) If so do a search for *Inverse Kinematics*